# Filter matrix in R according to difference between maximum and minimum values in rows

Tags: r, matrix, filter, max, min

I have a matrix A like:

```
 1   2   3   4   5
 2   3   6   4   3
 3   3   3   3   4
 2   3   3   3   4
```

I want to get only the rows where the difference between the maximum and minimum value in a row is larger than 2.

The function should return this matrix:

```
 1   2   3   4   5
 2   3   6   4   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the difference between min and max with `range` and `diff` and select rows where it is greater than 2.

```
A[apply(A, 1, function(x) diff(range(x))) > 2, ]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    2    3    6    4    3
```

---

For larger matrices you can also use `rowRanges` function from `matrixStats`.

```
mat <- matrixStats::rowRanges(A)
A[mat[, 2] - mat[, 1] > 2, ]
```